# Want to get items that are not unique

Tags: c#, linq

How can I re-write this to return the names of the entries which are not unique?

```
using Project.Site.Business;
using Project.Site.Models.Blocks;
using EPiServer;
using EPiServer.Core;
using EPiServer.ServiceLocation;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;

namespace Project.Site.Helpers.Attributes
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class UniqueHrefLangAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            var contentArea = value as ContentArea;

            if (contentArea != null)
            {
                var contentLoader = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentLoader>();
                var langsList = contentArea.Items?.Select(x => contentLoader.Get<HrefLangBlock>(x.ContentLink)).Select(x => x.HrefLangName).ToList();

                if(langsList != null)
                {
                    return (langsList.Count == langsList.Distinct().Count());
                }

            }

            return true;
        }

        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
        {
            return $"Languages in '{name}' must be unique.";
        }
    }


}
```

At the moment the error message reads as follows:

> Languages in 'Href Language' must be unique.

It was suggested to use something like this:

```
var query = lst.GroupBy(x => x)
              .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
              .Select(y => y.Key)
              .ToList();
```

But I have no idea how to combine the two.

Comment: please explain **ContentArea** and **HrefLangBlock**

Comment: ContentArea is specific to EPiServer: https://world.episerver.com/documentation/class-library/?documentId=cms/7/ab3bbfb1-5fdd-6650-3ebf-5e59f8f98490

Answer (score 0):

```
contentArea.Items?.Where(x => contentLoader.Get<HrefLangBlock>(x.ContentLink).Count() > 1).ToList();
```

Depending on your code, that might work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Visual Studio highlights Coun() and informs that HrefLangBlock does not contain a definition for count.

Comment: yeah, it must not be of type Enumerable, so it wont work. What exactly does that Get function return?

Comment: I think it returns this: System.Collections.Generic.List<string>

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of the below attribute should do what you want it to.

A different method of `ValidationAttribute` is overridden. The change from `IContentLoader.Get` to `IContentLoader.GetItems` is not strictly necessary but decreases the number of lines.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class UniqueHrefLangAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var contentArea = value as ContentArea;
        if (contentArea != null && contentArea.Items != null)
        {
            var contentLoader = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentLoader>();
            var blocks = contentLoader
                .GetItems(contentArea.Items.Select(i => i.ContentLink), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                .OfType<HrefLangBlock>();
            var duplicateHrefLangs = blocks
                .GroupBy(b => b.HrefLangName)
                .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
                .Select(grp => grp.Key)
                .ToList();
            if (duplicateHrefLangs.Any())
            {
                var errorMessage = $"Languages in '{validationContext.DisplayName}' must be unique. Duplicates: {string.Join(", ", duplicateHrefLangs)}";
                return new ValidationResult(errorMessage, new[] { validationContext.MemberName });
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

This validation attribute would run for any `ContentArea` property, disregarding any additional `AllowedTypes` restricting to just `HrefLangBlock` types. But that's outside of the point of the issue.

Cheers!